# How do you handle stage Event.RESIZE in an Actionscript3 application?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, resize

This has long bothered me.

When using stage resize, you could say something like this:

```
public class Preload extends MovieClip
{
     protected var main:Main;

     public function preloader()
     {

          this.main = new Main();
          this.addChild(this.main);

          stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, this.onResize);
     }

     protected function onResize(e:Event): void
     {
          this.main.x = stage.stageWidth>>1;
          this.main.y = stage.stageHeight>>1;
     }

}
```

What about if Main needs to also resize? I have many systems which respond to a resize event and I do not know if I should simply add a stage Event.RESIZE listener to every screen or if this should be controlled from a single location.

For example, add this.main.resize() to the onResize listener above then implement an IResizable interface on my screens for example?

What is best practice?

EDIT: Or should resize be part of something more generic, like invalidate()

Comment: Depending on the size of the application, and the number of things to scale, you have several options, also depending on what you want.

You want responsive, then add a resize listener for all things you want to size and/or reposition. If you just want to scale everything, you better just create a container and set the scaleX and scaleY for a container movieclip

Comment: Thanks Marijn. (I am not scaling). As you can see, I would have also taking this route but I heard multiple listeners is slow. See Pier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance it's better to have only 1 `Event.RESIZE` listener in your document class. Then propagate the event to all your sub classes and children with functions, or even better with the wonderful [Signals framework](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals) by Robert Penner.

If you need to scale your document class the easiest way is to put all your content inside a `Sprite` and scale that instead.